# Data Modeling Attributes

Tags: attributes, data-modeling, identity-column

I just had a quick question pertaining to converting a physical model to a logical model. Is an attribute the same thing as a column, in that, an attribute is just a logical name for column name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an attribute corresponds to a named table column. However, an attribute is not a name, rather, as a binary predicate, it has a name, a domain and a range. In the web ontology language OWL, an attribute is called a "data property", since its range is a data type.